# loading messages from a database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm kinda new to programming and with my basic knowladge i'm trying to create a page displays the messages saved in my database. (i already made it so messages can be put in)

i figured out how to display one message on the page but that's the first message in the database.

how can i make it that it not only displays one but it displays all of the messages?

this is my code so far..

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pwd = "";
$db_name = "berichten";

mysql_connect($host, $user, $pwd)or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB");

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY id ASC");
$id = 'id';
$name = 'naam';
$email = 'email';
$onderwerp = 'onderwerp';
$bericht = 'bericht';
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

echo 'name: '. $rows[$name] . '</br>' . 'e-mail: '. $rows[$email] . '</br>' . 'onderwerp: ' . $rows[$onderwerp] . '</br>' . 'bericht: ' . $rows[$bericht];
```

Comment: `while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql){ }`

Comment: Get off of the mysql extensions now.  Use mysqli or PDO. This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line :

```
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
```

To this :

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    echo 'name: '. $rows[$name] . '</br>' . 'e-mail: '. $rows[$email] . '</br>' . 'onderwerp: ' . $rows[$onderwerp] . '</br>' . 'bericht: ' . $rows[$bericht];
}
```

However, note that the MySQL extension is **deprecated**, and it is better to use the new MySQLi extension.

You can read about it here : http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Alternatively, you can use PDO : http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap your mysql_fetch_assoc in a while loop to iterate over the full result set.  Like this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY id ASC';
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["name"];
    echo $row["e-mail"];
    echo $row["onderwerp"];
    echo $row["bericht"];
}
```

Comment: edit suggestion: add link to http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Comment: and another suggestion: use pdo or mysqli

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mysql_fetch_array` or `mysql_fetch_assoc` from the PHP documentation. It is explained over there with examples.

Also, kindly avoid using `mysql` function as they are deprecated. Rather use `PDO` or `mysqli`

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop structure, use to be the base of every php/mysql code ;)

```
while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    echo 'name: '. $rows[$name] . '</br>' . 'e-mail: '. $rows[$email]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

by doing this:

```
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY id ASC");
```

You have essentially put all the rows from the database into this variable called `$sql`, which is an array of rows. Since each row has multiple items, the row can be treated as array as well. So, the `$sql is an Array of Arrays`

So you need to iterate over this little array called $sql like this:

```
    while($each = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
       // $each is a cursor, and loops over all the elements of the $sql sequentially.

    echo 'name: '. $each[$name] . '</br>' . 'e-mail: '. $each[$email] . '</br>' 
    . 'onderwerp: ' . $each[$onderwerp] . '</br>' . 'bericht: ' . $each[$bericht];

}
```